# How can i put a SQL count in a variable in C++ Builder 6?

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder

I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Carti WHERE TITLU='" + this->Titlu +"'
```

and I need to put the result into a variable and I need it to be integer.
This is the code:

```
AnsiString ttl="SELECT COUNT(TITLU) as NR FROM Carti WHERE TITLU='" + this->TitluC +"'";
CarteQuery -> Close();
CarteQuery -> SQL -> Clear();
CarteQuery -> SQL -> Add(ttl); 
CarteQuery -> Transaction -> StartTransaction(); 
CarteQuery -> Open; 
CarteQuery -> FieldByName("NR")->AsInteger;
```

But my program crush at this line

```
CarteQuery -> FieldByName("NR")->AsInteger;
```

Comment: Use an alias for the count `SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt FROM Carti`

Comment: it dosen't work, it dosen't put the result in that alias.

Comment: Can't be an SQL problem then but rather on the C++ side. Show your C++ code please. Otherwise we all just have to guess.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ and add the code there with some formatting.

Comment: Project Project1.exe raised exception class EIBClientError with message 'Field "NR" not found'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Comment: I don't know what a `CarteQuery` is, but this line: `CarteQuery -> Open; ` cannot have any effect. Is this meant to be a function call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not accessing a single field from multiple fields. You need to do this:

```
CarteQuery->Fields->FieldByName("NR")->AsInteger;
```

Please do provide feedback and let me know if that helped..